# How to specify random effects for panel/longitudinal data with level 2 predictor?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data

In the study of tweets pre- and post- metoo (set as Nov 2017), we are looking at whether there is gender differences in the use of masculine language in tweets for male and female social media users.

We have tweets collected for the period 2008-23 for 400 users. Some of these users were only active on Twitter before metoo and some only after metoo. But a majority of them have tweets in both the pre- and post- metoo period.

We are currently specifying the model as follows:

```
M1 = lmer(masculine_lang ~ gender * post_metoo + tweet_created_year + (1|user_id)
```

Where tweet_created_year is a factor variable.

We are not sure if this is a correct specification.

We have two major concerns.

- One, should we be using tweet_created_year as factor or as numeric
  (with year 2008 coded as 0, 2009 as 1, and so on)?
- Two, should we include tweet_created_year as random effect as follows:

`M2 = lmer(masculine_lang ~ gender * post_metoo + tweet_created_year + (1 + tweet_created_year|user_id)`

Alternatively, should we have the following specification?

```
M3 = lmer(masculine_lang ~ gender * post_metoo + (1|user_id) + (1|user_id:tweet_created_year)
```

We are confused what is the right approach as each one gives a different result for test of interaction hypothesis that gender * post_metoo is significant.

Also, if we are interested in seeing how the trajectories of masculine language use of men and women users change post_metoo (i.e., in the years 2018-23), how should we go about it?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Without knowing much about this (interesting!) subject, I'm not sure you need the year in the model at all. Perhaps you need it for some other reason, but not to investigate gender differences in the use of masculine language or in gender differences in the pre-post metoo change in the use of masculine language. So, I think the following model would work (I assume "post_metoo" is a two-level categorical variable indicating whether the tweet was posted prior to or after metoo):

```
mod<-lmer(masculine_lang ~ (1|user_id)+gender*post_metoo)
```

When it comes to trajectories, I'd suggest using latent (growth) curve models  with gender as a time-invariant covariate. See for instance [this](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/latent-growth-curve-analysis) and [this](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/growth.html) resource.

EDITED IN: I see you do need the year. I suppose you can enter it as a categorical predictor with each year as level. Or if you believe year can be considered as a continuous predictor, you can enter it as numeric too.

Comment: It may be useful to have `year` in the model in case there are changes in `masculine_lang` over time (that are separate from `post_metoo`).

Comment: Of course, if they are interested in those changes - but it wasn't clear to me if that was the case.

Comment: Thank you, @Sointu. The reason we think we need tweet_created_year is to rule out the explanation that masculine_lang changed over time, and not because of the specific event. Also, for any growth model, we do need tweet_created_year, right?

Comment: It's important even if they are *not* interested in those changes. Imagine there is a gradual decrease over time and then a sudden decrease after the event of interest (metoo). If `year` is not included, then the entire decrease will be attributed to `post_metoo`. In other words, the parameter estimate for `post_metoo` (and any associated inference) would be biased unless `year` is included.

Comment: Oh, you're right @mkt - I'll edit my response. Sunsan, growth models are specified differently than regression models, you would probably want to enter each year's masculine_lang scores as indicators of the latent intercept and slope, so "year" would be entered that way.

Comment: Thank you, @Sointu. Now that `tweet_created_year` is back in the equation, the question is how to specify it in the regression equation. Should it be as - 1) `tweet_created_year`; 2) `(tweet_created_year|user_id)`; 3) `tweet_created_year + (tweet_created_year|user_id)`; 4) `(1|tweet_created_year) + (1|user_id)`; 5) `(1|user_id) + (1|tweet_created_year:user_id)`; OR 6) `tweet_created_year + (1|user_id) + (1|tweet_created_year:user_id)` ?

Comment: I have to say I'm not sure what would be the best approach, but I would probably check the relationship between year and masculine_lang visually (with year as continuous), and if it's roughly linear, I'd use year as continuous numeric predictor. If there is curvilinearity in the relationship, I'd also add year squared as predictor. But I hope someone with more insight comments too.

Comment: ...so that would mean masculine_lang ~ (1|user_id)+gender*post_metoo+tweet_created_year (with the possible addition of +tweet_created_year^2)

Comment: @Sunsan Some of those questions are not possible to answer without knowing more about the data. I suggest developing a new question based on that and including plots of the patterns over time to help people answer.